# Array dimension in c++ 11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dimension

I have studied in C++ Primer that the dimension of an array should be a const expression but the following code compiles and gives the desired result. Why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
unsigned int bufsize = 10;
int h[bufsize]={};
for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    cout<<h[i]<<endl;
}
```

But if I add the following:

```
constexpr int a = bufsize;
```

Then the compiler shows error meaning that bufsize is not a constant expression then why is the program compiling correctly otherwise if the dimension of the array should be constant expression

Comment: Most compilers accept some non-conforming code by default (that's called *extensions*). If you use GCC or Clang, add `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors` flags to disable that behaviour. (Replace `??` with language version: `17`, `14`, `11`, ...)

Comment: I am following the gnu gcc compiler in codeblocks

Comment: See the edited comment then.

Comment: My wish is that gcc or whatever compiler you're using would turn this option **off** by default.  Then less questions like this (and less posts with this code code) would occur.

Comment: Also, `constexpr int a = bufsize;` doesn't work because you can't initialize a `constexpr` variable with non-`constexpr` expression. Try `constexpr int a = 10;` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie An understandable wish, but then gcc would fail to compile _lots_ of existing software packages that use those extensions (without build modifications to re-enable the extensions). Balancing compatibility with strict standard compliance is a delicate art...

Comment: @TypeIA how about a compromise and issue a warning by default (which is after all mandatory for standard compliance)?

Comment: Yes, but I put most of the blame on `gcc` for this.  We now have coding websites where they show samples of supposed C++ code that uses these extensions.  Then either the newbie C++ programmer believes the code they're writing is valid, or worse, the newbie C++ programmer takes their code to Visual Studio, and are stumped why their code doesn't compile.  Then we get the plethora of questions asked here on why the code doesn't compile on Visual Studio.  The gcc engineers should have seen this, and just put a cutoff date on the extension being "on" by default.

Comment: @user2079303 You would not expect a warning when using a documented extension. As long as the default mode is GnuC++, we are stuck.

Comment: @BaummitAugen my non-explicit suggestion is to use a standard compliant mode by default (allow extensions but warn), and require an option to explicitly enable GNU extensions.

Comment: @user2079303 Ah ok. I misunderstood.